# How to compile WebRTC properly with Visual Studio in debug?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, webrtc, chromium, ninja

I'm trying to compile WebRTC, but because we use a number of libraries, some of which are closed source and beyond our control, how it gets compiled is rather sensitive to match. I've already had to edit the `build/config/win/BUILD.gn` script to use `/MDd` and `/MD` build flags instead of `/MTd` and `/MT` respectively, as we use the multi-threaded DLL runtime. To build, we run

```
gn gen out/Debug --args="is_debug=true is_clang=false use_lld=false visual_studio_version=2019"
ninja -C out/Debug
```

However, when linking against webrtc.lib, it fails with multiple errors citing a mismatch between `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL`. I've seen this error plenty, it happens when linking a release-built library (`_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=2`) with a debug executable (`_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0`). However that's clearly not how I've compiled it. I've tried adding `/DEBUG` (which should be implied by `/MDd` as far as I know) but it produces an identical library with the same issue. I've confirmed checking the generated .ninja scripts that these arguments are in the `cflags`.

Is there a way to get ninja to properly observe the debug flags?

Comment: You really cannot. Use ninja and other build tools that WebRTC native API documentation recommends. I tried to create a Visual Studio build for two months, got older by 5 years during that time, failed and gave up.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Although, [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/) is a powerful library, it looks terrible for native development. Neither good documentation nor examples, especially for using outside Google sources.
Please, try this one argument, that helped me:
 `enable_iterator_debugging=true`

Answer (score 0):

I don't deal with libwebrtc myself, but I have heard that long term you might have a better experience pulling out all the files and using your own build system. [Orchid](https://github.com/OrchidTechnologies/orchid/tree/master/min-webrtc) did this, but I haven't looked at it myself.

There are other C/C++ WebRTC implementations if you are doing DataChannels only that might be helpful also!

Comment: Literally the only thing we're using is Peer Connection API to send a single video stream from our application to a browser running on a trusted device on the same network. I've looked around at alternative implementations but the ones I've found are either defunct or are limited in scope.